# How to output prompt data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code and am trying to do what is asked in the comments:
I have the following code and am trying to do what is asked in the comments:
I have the following code and am trying to do what is asked in the comments:
I have the following code and am trying to do what is asked in the comments:
I have the following code and am trying to do what is asked in the comments:
I have the following code and am trying to do what is asked in the comments:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project 14</title>
  <style>
    html {margin:1em; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
    h2 {clear:both;}
    .box {width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid #000; background-color:#ddd;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header><h1>Project 14</h1></header>

  <h2>One</h2>
  <button id="button-one">Alert</button>
  <script>
  var buttonone = document.getElementById("button-one");
  buttonone.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction(){
alert ("button was clicked");}
  </script>

  <h2>Two</h2>
  <button id="button-two">What is your name?</button>
  <div id="name-output"></div>
  <script>
  var buttontwo = document.getElementById("button-two");
  buttontwo.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction(){
prompt ("What is your name?");}
var personname = prompt("What is your name?");
var nameoutput = document.getElementById("name-ouput");
var newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
var copy = document.createTextNode("Your name is" +personname)
newParagraph.appendChild (copy)
var len = personname.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        nameoutput.appendChild(newParagraph.cloneNode(true));
    }

  /*
  1. When "button-two" is clicked, use a "prompt" to ask for the users name
  2. Wrap the result in a paragraph and output it to "name-output" x times (with x being the number of characters in the name)
  3. Each paragraph should start with the text "Your name is:"
  */
  </script>

  <h2>Three</h2>
  <button id="button-three">Output Colors</button>
  <ul id="color-list"></ul>
  <script>
  var mycolorlist = ['green','yellow','blue','red','brown','purple','pink']
  var colorlist = document.getElementById("color-list");
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  var copy = document.createTextNode(mycolorlist )
  newLi.appendChild (copy)
  /*
  1. Create an array with the seven colors of the rainbow
  2. Loop through the array and append an "li" for each color to the "color-list" ul
  */
  </script>

  <h2>Four</h2>
  <div id="box1" class="box">Mouse Events</div>
  <script>
  var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
  box1.addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction);
function myFunction(){
  console.log('mouse entered the box');
  box1.addEventListener("mouseout", myFunction);
function myFunction(){
  console.log('mouse left the box');
}

  /*
  1. Add two event listeners to the box. One for when the mouse enters, the other when it leaves
  2. When the cursor enters the box, log to the console "Mouse entered the box".
  3. When the cursor leaves the box, log to the console "Mouse left the box".
  */
  </script>

  <h2>Five</h2>
  <label>Input 1: <input type="text" id="input1"></label><br>
  <label>Input 2: <input type="text" id="input2"></label><br>
  <button id="button-compare">Compare</button>
  <script>
  var buttoncompare = document.getElementById("button-compare");
  var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
  var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
  buttoncompare.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction(){ if (input1 == input2) {console.log('true');} else {console.log('false');}
}
  /*
  1. Add an event listener to the "button-compare" button
  2. When the button is clicked, compare the values of the two inputs
  3. Output to the console the results of the comparison (true or false)
  */
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code you've shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a paragraph as you have done then [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) it as many times as you need

```
var buttontwo = document.getElementById("button-two");
buttontwo.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var personname = prompt("What is your name?");
    var nameoutput = document.getElementById("name-ouput");

    var newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    var copy = document.createTextNode(personname);
    newParagraph.appendChild(copy)

    var len = personname.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //clone the paragraph as many times as the number of characters
        nameoutput.appendChild(newParagraph.cloneNode(true));
    }

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eb98h337/)

---

You should not have multiple functions with same name

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Project 14</title>
        <style>
            html {margin:1em; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
            h2 {clear:both;}
            .box {width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid #000; background-color:#ddd;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header><h1>Project 14</h1></header>

        <h2>Two</h2>
        <button id="button-two">What is your name?</button>
        <div id="name-output"></div>
        <script>

            var buttontwo = document.getElementById("button-two");
            buttontwo.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

            function myFunction() {
                var personname = prompt("What is your name?");
                var nameoutput = document.getElementById("name-output");

                var newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
                var copy = document.createTextNode(personname);
                newParagraph.appendChild(copy)

                var len = personname.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    //clone the paragraph as many times as the number of characters
                    nameoutput.appendChild(newParagraph.cloneNode(true));
                }

            }
            /*
            1. When "button-two" is clicked, use a "prompt" to ask for the users name
            2. Wrap the result in a paragraph and output it to "name-output" x times (with x being the number of characters in the name)
            3. Each paragraph should start with the text "Your name is:"
            */
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, but why will it not show up in my document? Do I need to use a document.write ?

Comment: @Syd check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: I see: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @Syd that means your script block has a syntax error... can you share the updated script tag and its contents